# Are there any gyms in the Anime/Manga where the Pokemon trainer has to first fight other trainers?

Tags: pokemon

In the Pokemon video-games inside a Gym, aside from the Gym Leader there are a bunch of trainers and generally you need to fight at least one to get to the Gym Leader.

In the anime, I have seen so far none of the gyms shown follow the same format but I've only seen up to Diamond and Pearl when Palkia and Dialga are summoned.

I am wondering if in the anime or any manga, there is a Gym which follows the same format as that from the games, where the challenging trainer has to face a gauntlet of trainers before they face the Gym Leader?

Comment: As far as battling other trainers in the gym, I couldn't say. In the Black and White manga, however, I do recall that the gym puzzles were present in at least some of the gyms.

Answer (score 4):

The *Pokémon Adventures* manga series does sometimes include the other trainers and puzzles in the gyms. In *Pokémon Adventures: Diamond and Pearl Platinum*, Lady Berlitz usually does battle the other gym trainers and complete the puzzles of the gym, however it is usually glossed over. Instead, the manga usually focuses on Diamond and Pearl as they try to catch a glimpse of Lady's progress since they are barred from entering the earlier gyms. For instance, in volume 2, Lady Berlitz visits Gardenia's gym. On page 13, the guard statue explains that Lady Berlitz has to defeat four trainers hidden in the forest maze and then make her way to Gardenia. On page 15, after getting kicked out of the gym, Diamond and Pearl find a window to watch the gym challenge and discover that Lady has already reached Gardenia:

> It's amazing, Pearl! Lady got through the maze already and beat all of the preliminary trainers! She's already facing Gardenia!
>   
> -Diamond, *Pokémon Adventures: Diamond and Pearl Platinum* Volume 2, pages 14-15

Some later gym puzzles, such as the math problems in Fantina's gym, were shown more explicitly.

Likewise, in the *Black and White* chapter, gym puzzles were shown. At the first gym, the puzzle was to step on a switch representing the Pokémon type that was effective against the Pokémon type on a series of curtains. When Bianca interrupted Black's gym challenge by stepping on an incorrect button, the three gym leaders agreed to a three-on-three battle if Cheren and Black helped her out and the three of them made it through the curtains.

Answer (score 2):

Well, generally speaking, no, Ash has never fought any other trainers in the gym, and you'll probably never see it, because technically speaking, when you watch the anime, you've seen just about how long it takes for a battle to take place, which is usually a whole episode. Ranging from when the Pokemon looks beat but then gets back up, or there's another fight also going on at the current moment, they still take about a whole episode per battle. If you tried including the other trainers in the gym, then that could maybe at an extra 3 episodes per part of the series that ash gets to a gym. Also, the only time you would've seen the other trainers was in that animation of *pokemon origins,* where they added the mega stone to go with the Charizard. Even then, you didn't really see ash fight the other trainers in Brock's gym, you just saw them.

Hope this helped,
- Matt